# Is mutually private protocol negotiation possible?

Tags: privacy, anonymity, fingerprinting

Say I have two peers that wish to engage in a protocol with multiple sub-protocols. Naturally, it is necessary for them to negotiate which sub-protocol they should use. But what if the peers wish to be anonymous? How can they agree on which sub-protocol to use without fingerprinting themselves with the list that their client supports?

Naïvely, one could use private set intersection - but this would allow a malicious party to spoof using the full list of sub-protocols. We can partially solve this by using asymmetric PSI schemes that reveal the intersection only to one party, assuming that one is more likely to be malicious than the other. While this may be appropriate in the client-server setting, it is insufficient for the peer-to-peer setting.

So far, the only solution I have come up with is to randomly select from the intersection before revealing it to the peers. However, I am not aware of any literature on this variation, and do not know enough about cryptography to hazard an attempt. Also, this may be a flawed line of thought to begin with.

Comment: I suggest you concentrate on **what** you are trying to accomplish instead of **how** you think it should be done. *Hammers ... nails*